# How to play a video by clicking it without controls and reveal controls after play is clicked? in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

```
export const UseRefPlayer = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef();
  
  const handlePlay = () => {
    videoRef.current.play();
  };
    
  const handlePause = () => {
    videoRef.current.pause();
  };
    
  return (
    <>
      <div className="videoplayer-buttons">
        <button className="play-button" onClick={handlePlay}>
          Play
        </button>
        <button className="pause-button" onClick={handlePause}>
          Pause
        </button>
      </div>
      <video width="100%" ref={videoRef} onClick={handlePlay} controls>
        <source src="{videoURL}" />
      </video>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried adding a pause button but it shows anyways regardless, then I tried adding a `poster={url}` but the controls showing anyways overlaying the poster.
I'd want the controls to show only after the video is played.

Answer (score 0):

actually, here is an answer, Inside handlePlayToggle, we check if the video is paused using video.paused. If it's paused, we play it; otherwise, we pause it.

We also toggle the controlsVisible state based on the video's current state. If the video is paused, we hide the controls; if it's playing, we show the controls.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export const UseRefPlayer = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef();
  const [controlsVisible, setControlsVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleVideoClick = () => {
    const video = videoRef.current;

    if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
      setControlsVisible(true);
    } else {
      video.pause();
      setControlsVisible(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <video
        width="100%"
        ref={videoRef}
        onClick={handleVideoClick}
        controls={controlsVisible}
        poster={"posterUrl"}
      >
        <source src="videoUrl" />
      </video>
    </>
  );
};
```